# Model non-negative zero-inflated with continuous data?

Tags: glmm, zero-inflation

I have a few observations (58) because my same is really small since we're studying the performance of some incredibly rare individuals. Anyway, we're measuring the time durations for some behaviours but one of the variables has a lot of zeros. How can I handle that? I read that the non-negative zero-inflated can only be used for counts, then what's the option for something measured in seconds?

Here's what my data looks like:
[image]

Edit: would the Tobit regression work in this case?

Comment: Zero inflation is a specific form of mixture: you mix a point mass at zero with some other distribution. You can use this machinery with pretty much any "other" distribution, e.g., [the gamma here](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/Rfast2/html/zigamma.reg.html). Just be aware that it will be hard to deduce any group or other differences with your small data set. Can you be more specific as to what you want to explore (differences in conditional means, or in the incidence of zeros)? It may well be that some other method is better suited to your specific question.

Comment: I want to explore the difference in conditional means, exactly. We observed these rare individuals doing something VS typical ones and we want to know if there's any difference between the two groups. I understand I have a small data set but for the situation I'm in is pretty standard

Comment: OK. So do you have something like 29 "special" individuals and 29 controls, or 58 "specials", plus a (large) number of controls? If it's just a question of differences in means, it may be feasible to just run a t-test, or a permutation test for differences in means, rather than building a complex model on few observations - though, per above, that is possible.

Comment: For instance, you would need to figure out confidence intervals on the estimated means from your zero-inflated or mixture model. [Here is one search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bconfidence-interval%5D+mixture), it might make sense to run similar searches for zero inflation instead of mixtures, or to ask a separate question if you do decide to go with (e.g.,) a zero inflated gamma.

Comment: Tobit is for censored data. [Look at the examples here.](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/tobit-models/) All are about an underlying reality where the *measurement* cuts off at some point. In your case, it's *not* like your time durations are actually negative, but your watch can only measure times at least zero. In your case, the variable is truly zero, i.e., there are two separate data generating processes at work, one of which always yields zero, and the other one yields some nonnegative number. I would rather more lean towards zero inflation or mixtures here. (Or indeed a simple t test.)